# Refreshing the page using Node.js / Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I need to refresh the page in my small Node and Express app as soon as the user connects. I have tried `res.redirect('index.html')` in the second snippet, but it throws an error when I try to connect to the root URL.

The following code is run when the user connects to the root URL:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/index.html')
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
});
```

and I detect when the user connects with:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` should NOT be inside another route.  That needs to go up at the top level at the same level as your `app.get()`.  As it is you're just adding a new duplicate middleware every time the `/` route is hit.  That will take more and more memory over time.

Comment: What error do you get?  Do you have a route installed for `/index.html`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have fixed my routes, thank you so much for that advice. The error I got was TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined

Comment: You're getting that error from what line of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //  res.redirect('back');
    // OR
  res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
});
```